# Why is my php mail not being received?

Tags: email, iis, lotus-notes, php

I have a simple form and I'm attempting to have an email sent upon submission. I'm running XP Pro (this is a side project at work, not my pc) so I have IIS up and running, I have Lotus Notes client 6.5 installed. I've configured my php.ini files as well as my IIS.

```
$to = "recipientemail@xxx.com";
$subject = "Hi!";
$body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";
if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
} else {
echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
}
```

My php.ini

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = MY.IP.MY.IP 
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = myemail@xxx.com
```

I don't receive any errors and it echos Message Sent so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Initially I had it set to use localhost and it wasn't working so now I'm just using my IP which I have also defined in my IIS settings, I've also defined the loopback and my IP under relay restrictions. My only guess is maybe something isn't setup to play with LN properly, like maybe its looking for Outlook?
Also I don't have pear installed and don't care to use it, also tried PHPMailer to no avail, I just want to get this working.

Comment: You need to check that with the log of your mailserver. PHP itself has not control about recieving messages, it only passes them to the mailserver and if that worked `mail()` returns true. Double-Check with http://php.net/mail

Comment: Exact Duplicate: [why is php mail script not sending mail](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3602741/367456)

Comment: I'm running LN client 6.5, does this mean I need to use my Domino server as an outbound server?

Comment: I can not tell you. Probably you might want to ask the server administrator about that?

Comment: Hmm well that is out of state and this is just a side project so I don't think I would get much assistance, I have the IP for the Domino server so I'll plug that in and see what happens, as for checking the server logs, I don't have that access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the server at MY.IP.MY.IP is not running a SMTP server (not a mail client), then your call to mail() is not going to actually do anything.

If you do have a valid SMTP server, it is most likely going to need a user/pass to accept any of your mail (or it would be an open relay for spammers). The exception to this is often a mail server will accept mail from the localhost as trusted.

I don't think php.ini supports SMTP AUTH credentials, so you might want to try the PEAR Mail package and directly send with a SMTP server you already have access credentials to use.

http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/

Comment: Ok well I've tried using PHPMailer, HMailServer, and sendmail, I couldn't seem to get any of them to work, so I've gone back to pear, I can install pear fine, but when I run pear upgrade I get "Error getting channel info from pear.php.net:" I'm guessing the proxy server here is getting in the way, I'm honestly not sure if that's causing any issues, however when attempt to send email now I get Fatal error: Class 'Mail' not found in C:\wamp\www\etc\etc